# Simple CNN model four image inputs to detect two classes

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, training-data

I am working on a project where I must use four different images as inputs. I take the inputs run them through a simple model and detect two classes.I am really struggling in the actual setup of the model.
Not sure if I am on the right track. I haven't been able to run the code since I am still unsure of the architecture of the model. The code below is my model how its setup currently. I have all the images already. I took one image and split it into four. Then using the four images, detect one of two classes. If this doesn't make sense or I am taking the wrong direction with this please help.'

```html
# import the necessary packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dropout
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense ,LSTM,concatenate,Input,Flatten

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten
import keras

# define four sets of inputs
inputA = Input(shape=(200, 200, 3))
inputB = Input(shape=(200, 200, 3))
inputC = Input(shape=(200, 200, 3))
inputD = Input(shape=(200, 200, 3))

# merge all input images
merged = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([inputA, inputB, inputC, inputD])
    
# the first branch operates on the first input through the fourth input
dense1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu')(merged)
output = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu')(dense1)
 
# apply a FC layer and then a regression prediction on the
# combined outputs
z = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(output)
z = keras.layers.Dense(9, activation="softmax")(z)


# then output a single value then our model will accept the inputs of the two branches and
# model = Model(inputs=[tt.output, y.output, t.output, w.output], outputs=z)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

I think the model is setup correctly to run using four images as inputs, but now I need to setup the classes. My idea with is , to set up a CNN that looks at four different pictures of the same tree. Using those four images to detect the type of tree. I want all four images to be for one tree. Then detect the tree. After detecting the tree moving onto the next four images for a different tree.

Thanks everyone I am very grateful for all your inputs and help.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow community.

This is just a suggestion but, I'm assuming you're not cropping a single image to four right? These are four different images. If that's the case, it would be better to use 4 conv layers separately for the inputs and concat the output before feeding to the dense layer.
And you said you have two outputs right? Why are there 9 units in the SoftMax then?

Comment: Thank you!! Yes good call I changed the output units to 3. I didn't crop the image. Is the best way to label the images using hot label. I have three labels I believe. So it goes I have four images that equal one class, but i have 3 classes I am trying to detect.